# Iterate over all currently loaded fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager. It has Fragments. When those Fragments are created, they load data from the server. When the user selects a menu item, I want to tell those fragments to filter their data without reloading from the server.

To do this, I have a subclass of FragmentPagerAdapter which keeps a List to hold a reference to each Fragment as it is created. When the menu item is selected, I simply iterate over that collection and call a method on each Fragment.

The problem arises when the device is rotated. The framework automatically restores the fragments to their parent view, without calling the getItem method of my adapter, meaning that my List is empty.

How can I either repopulate that List when the device is rotated, or obtain a list of all of the ViewPager's child Fragments without keeping a list?

EDIT: It may be important to note that my ViewPager lives in a Fragment, and that Fragment gets hot swapped via a side navigation menu. In other words, my ViewPager is not owned by an Activity, and there are some known issues about ViewPager not cleaning up its child fragments correctly which may be exacerbating the problem.

Comment: You might switch to my `ArrayPagerAdapter`, which makes this easier: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager

Comment: I am in the position where I cannot include open source software in this app. Your solution looks really nice, but I'm not sure how it solves my problem.

I have added edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Get Current visible fragment in ViewPager](http://androidprofessionals.blogspot.in/2013/06/get-current-visible-fragment-page-in.html)

The author basically suggests 2 similar approaches which are to attach tags on fragment creation and keep track of it.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(myFragment, "Some Tag").commit();
```

Then retrieve the tag like so:

```
int index = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
String tag = mPageReferenceMap.get(index);
Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```